# How to Stop my cat from biting my hand?

Tags: cats

I have a six months old kitten who got spayed 20 days back. I play with her with an interactive toy, half an hour in the afternoon and one hour in the evening. When I am working, I play one hour in the evening. She has many toys.
She still keeps attacking my legs and hand. I try to distract her too, she still finds my hand more attractive to bite. How can I stop this from happening? When I am working, I can’t play with her all the time. So how can I teach her that this is a bad habit? She is a domestic cat.

Comment: 90 minutes a day is not enough playtime for a kitten; this is the reason many rescues and shelters encourage (or even enforce) adopting more than one kitten at a time.

Comment: How many hours a day playtime is enough for cats ?

Comment: With kittens, it's quite a bit, that's why the recommendation is to adopt in pairs (or more). As they age, it'll be considerably less.